# Compile error - Could not find or load class in java error

Tags: java

```
package IO;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class driver {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int s;

        try {

            //Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            //System.out.println("Enter The number of files you want to create");
            //s = in.nextLine();
            //takes the number of files

            ArrayList<String> obj = new ArrayList<String>();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println("Enter the number of files you want to create");
            String num = br.readLine();
            int x = Integer.parseInt(num);

            // takes the names of file
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                System.out.println("Enter the name for file:");
                String name = br.readLine();
                Integer.parseInt(name);
                obj.add(name);
            }

        } catch (IOException o) {
            System.out.println("Exception^^^^^^^^^^^^^");

        }
    }
}
```

Here above is my code but when i compile it on command line like javac driver.java and then java driver it gives me error that could not load main class main ... please help me with sorting of this error .. this code btw contains file handling which is to be implemented later!

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Comment: what? pls help me compile this code successfully.

Comment: You should really fix your indentation.

Comment: @Mah Noor The question I linked to asked a very similar question which also has some pretty good answers.

Comment: Try `java IO.driver`?

Comment: again error .. could not load file IO.driver

Comment: @Mah Noor what command are you using to compile?

Comment: It gives you *exactly what* error? 'Error like XXX' is of no use. Don't suppresss or mangle relevant information.

Comment: its workinf fine now thanks

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code check the following code it works for me..

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Driver{

    public static void main(String args[]){

    int s;

    try{
        ArrayList<String> obj = new ArrayList<String>();
        BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the number of files you want to create");     
        String num = br.readLine();
        int x=Integer.parseInt(num);

        // takes the names of file

        for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
        System.out.println("Enter the name for file:");
        String name = br.readLine();
        Integer.parseInt(name);
        obj.add(name);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
    }
}
```

Comment: its still giving error of couldnt load file demo :/

Comment: oh THANKYOU it's working but dont know what was the problem with it :/

Comment: You had package IO; statement, The declared package "IO" does not match excepted package. If you want to know about packages Go and have look this tutorial - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/ . Next thing is best practice to use lowercase for package names.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you locating the file correctly?
2. Remove the `package IO;` and then compile it.
   It is compiled successfully.
   [image]